# gcloud util installation crashed on Windows 10

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I want to install gcloud ssh component on Windows 10 Home in order to ssh GCE instances. But it failed showing the following message.

```
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 347.0.0
Installing components from version: 347.0.0

These components will be installed.

Name: gcloud Beta Commands
Version: 2019.05.17
Size: < 1 MiB

For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Creating update staging area
10%
(snip)
100%
100%
ERROR: gcloud crashed (Error): [('C:\\Users\\tafut\\gcloud\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\funcsigs\\docs\\index.rst', 'C:\\Users\\tafut\\gcloud\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\funcsigs\\docs\\index.rst', 'symbolic link privilege not held'), ('C:\\Users\\tafut\\gcloud\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\mock\\docs\\changelog.txt', 'C:\\Users\\tafut\\gcloud\\google-cloud-sdk.staging\\platform\\gsutil\\third_party\\mock\\docs\\changelog.txt', 'symbolic link privilege not held')]

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Here is the gcloud version installed.

```
$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 347.0.0
bq 2.0.69
core 2021.06.25
gsutil 4.64
```

Comment: On Windows 10, the CLI is not installed relative to a user's home directory path. I recommend uninstalling and rebooting your system. Then install the current version. However, the error `symbolic link privilege not held` means the user does not have permission or the file system does not support that feature. You may have more than one issue with your system.

Comment: Run `gpedit.msc`. What are the settings for Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment → Create symbolic links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i suggest you once uninstall cloud sdk and reinstall it again,sometimes most of the errors will get resolved through reinstalling .refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) documentation to uninstall.you can refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) documentation for installing it. and use any of this methods to [ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools)

Comment: Thanks. It fixed by reinstalling as you said. I seemed to mess up installation.

Comment: thanks for the suggested workaround, a pity they are still unable to make a stable update process

Answer (score 3):

I was using `gcloud` command from the "Git bash" in Windows. Even though I opened the "Git bash" with "Run as Administrator", `gcloud` would crash.

Instead, I opened `Google Cloud SDK Shell` (I still used "Run as Administrator"), and the gcloud commands worked without crashing.